# Deploying and running an ASP.NET application on a webLogic server

Tags: asp.net, iis, weblogic

I'm a .net developer.
I have a project that I might get into.
The thing is, the servers are WebLogic.
I don't know a lot on this subject so I wanted to know if I can deploy my asp.NET application on that server (or what I have to do for that)

Thanks for any help

Comment: How it is related to java?

Comment: I removed java tag but waiting for approval

Comment: No, you cannot deploy ASP.Net applications on Weblogic Server.